# DataGrid virtualization on collectionview refresh

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid, virtualization

Specifically this is a follow-up to this question [DataGrid filter performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845080/wpf-datagrid-performance-filter-performance), but there are many more similar questions relating to WPF DataGrid performance on StackOverflow.

After a lot of profiling and going through .NET source code, I have realized that many performance issues, such as *filtering and sorting*, boil down just one issue: ***A CollectionView.Reset event does not recycle containers (like scrolling does).***

What I mean is that instead of assigning the existing rows a new datacontext, all rows are removed from the visual tree, new rows are generated and added, and a layout cycle (measure and arrange) is performanced.

**So the main question is:** Has anyone successfully managed to work around this? E.g. by manually manipulating the ItemContainerGenerator, or by creating their own version of the DataGridRowsPresenter?

So this is the gist of my approach so far.

```
public class CollectionViewEx
{
    public event EventHandler Refresh;

    public override void Refresh()
    {
        Refresh?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class DataGridEx : DataGrid
{
    protected override OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldSource, IEnumerable newSource)
    {
        if (newSource is CollectionViewEx cvx)
        {
            cvx.Refresh += (o,a) => OnViewRefreshing;
        }
    }

    private void OnViewRefreshing()
    {
        RowsPresenter.Refresh();
    }
}

public class DataGridRowsPresenterEx : DataGridRowsPresenter
{
    public void Refresh()
    {
        var generator = (IRecyclingItemContainerGenerator)ItemContainerGenerator;

        generator.Recycle(new GeneratorPosition(0, 0), ???);         
        RemoveInternalChildRange(0, VisualChildrenCount);

        using (generator.StartAt(new GeneratorPosition(-1, 0), GeneratorDirection.Forward))
        {
            UIElement child;
            bool isNewlyRealised = false;
            while ((child = generator.GenerateNext(out isNewlyRealised) as UIElement) != null)
            {
                AddInternalChild(child);
                generator.PrepareItemContainer(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the results are very confusing - obviously because I don't quite understand how to work with the ICG.

I have looked through .net source code to see their implementations (when adding/removing/replacing items), and also found a couple of online resources on how to create a new virtualized panel (e.g. virtualizingwrappanel), but none really address this particular issue, where we want to *reuse all existing containers for a new set of items*.

**So the secondary question is:** Can anyone explain if this approach is even possible? How would I do it?

Comment: Have you considered not using a collectionview for filtering? Read the data into one collection. Filter it from that using linq into the bound collection. It's the same objects so your memory overhead is pretty small. Or read just the data you need.

Comment: It is not the collectionview which is the problem, but the way the datagrid(rowspresenter) reacts to the NotifyCollectionChanged.Reset event, regenerating all containers instead of recycling them. It is essentially equivalent to changing the ItemsSource on the datagrid, so filtering a bound collection with linq and raising the propertychanged has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I never use reset directly from CollectionView because a methode on CollectionView's Source do it. This IList is modified for my needs. I did it like Paul McClean explained [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization).

In this class you could notify OnCollectionChanged to inform the CollectionView. [sondergard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/983771/sondergard) explained what NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset do. But NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace keep running the recyling for the Items.

Maybe my research helps.